# How do I turn on auto code completion in IntelliJ?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

As the title says, how?
I have looked around the internet and found a bunch of answers saying to go to

Settings|Code|Code completion

but it seems that settings category is gone in version 14 of IntelliJ, which is the one I am using. The reason that it's off in the first place is because the teacher in my Java course has made his own custom code inspection .JAR-file, which when I installed it, turned my automatic code completion off. I have changed that profile back to the default one in every category of the settings that I have found so far, without results. Please help!

Comment: have you specified the JDK path ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

Check this option.
If it is not worked, check "keymap" option.
Maybe key was using for other action.

Comment: THANK YOU!! I thought my IntelliJ was broken there for a while!